# How to allow string both to match certain expression and not to contain another string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a telephone number checking regex:

`/^\+\d{1,3}[\d ]*$/` (it matches `+7 5165761074`).

I need this regexp also not to allow `0000000` and `1234567` inside.

Comment: You'd be better of doing two separate checks with the other one looking for `indexOf('000000')` and `1234567`

Comment: I'm using ExtJS and it's automatically ckeck input field value with `regex` property. It's more comfortable to use it instead of putting listener on field `change` event.

Comment: You need to normalize the input (remove the spaces) before checking, or restrict the user to some rigid structure (you can provide a few boxes for user to fill in: country code, area code, number).

Comment: Yeah. Not easy way ). Seems like I've got to validate field value on blur with validator function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use negative lookahead

```
/^\+(?!0000000)(?!1234567)\d{1,3}[\d ]*$/
```

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev2.shtml

The actual expression in the lookaheads might be slightly different depending on what exactly you mean with "not allow inside".

Comment: `+6 0000000` matches and `+6 1234567` matches too.